# Basic MS SQL Server 2008 questions

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, import, installation, migrate

Can you import (or migrate) SQL Server 2005 databases to SQL Server 2008?

Is it possible to have the same 2005 and 2008 running on the same machine without complications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can restore a backup from SQL 2005 in SQL 2008. You can also have instances of both on the same machine.

Edit: This question has been asked before (more or less). [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204212/can-an-ms-sql-2005-backup-be-restored-onto-an-instance-of-ms-sql-2008)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and Yes.

The fastest way to move from one to the other that I have found is just to do a backup from SQL 2005 and a restore to SQL 2008.

I have both running side-by-side on my dev box without issue.